# Как сделать вертикальный GUI.Toolbar в Unity?

Tags: unity3d, unity-container

По умолчанию кнопки в нем стоят в ряд по горизонтали. Как можно сделать по вертикали?

Answer (score 1):

Вместо этого использовала GUI.SelectionGrid, с параметром xCount 1.